# Conditional query in SQLite

Tags: sqlite, exists

Way to do in sqlite what is typical in most DB?

```
if exists(select 1 from tosync where tbname = "%s" and tbid = %d 
   and (act = 1 and %d = 3 or act = 3 and %d = 1)
begin
  delete from tosync where tbname = "%s" and tbid = %d 
end
else
begin
  insert into tosync(tbname, tbid, act) values("%s", %d, %d);
end
```

Replaced values respectively are

```
 [TbName, tbid, act, act, TbName, tbid, TbName, tbid, act]
```

Please note, that this topic is not about `UPSERT` and similar issues available in sqlite.

Comment: Is upsert a new thing? First you need to declare your variables

Comment: @Edward what do you mean?

Comment: @Edward, excuse me, but your last comment didn't make your first question more clear to me. But I guess that for most UPSERT is not a new thing.

Comment: Well I am not familiar with SQLite, but I do know my way around T-SQL and just saying I have never heard of UPSERT, I thought maybe it was a misspelling. That being said I even just took a Microsoft examination for Database Fundamentals and I can say there was 0 in it or study guides about UPSERT

Comment: @Edward, I see. Then yes, in SQLite its an option. It is valid to execute `UPDATE OR INSERT`. See more in the comment below by Rik Lewis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do conditional queries in this way in SQLite.

You can however do INSERT ... WHERE NOT EXISTS ...

Check this out for more information... http://www.sqlite.org/lang_insert.html

Comment: do you suggest to run multiple queries one by one with copying `WHERE` conditions in both `INSERT` and `DELETE` statements?

Comment: I'm not really making a suggestion, just answering your question. Personally I'd probably try to run a SELECT initially, do the conditionally on my code and then run the appropriate queries. But I don't know your context, as you've not said.

Comment: I see. I was also thinking of that too, but I still had a hope that it's possible to be done inside one sql-query...

Comment: It was really strange to me to spent a plenty of hours and not finding any other questions about that issue.

Comment: Sorry, I don't think this is possible.

Comment: I will mark your comment as answer, because it gave the result. Below I will post my solution that includes your suggestion

Answer (score 0):

After a while solutuion was found for this particular situation.

I have to run both insert and delete queries in a row with same condition:

```
insert or replace into tosync (tbname,tbid,act) 
  select                        "%s" ,%d  ,%d 
where not exists(select 1 from tosync 
                 where tbname="%s" and tbid=%d and (act=1 and %d=3 or act=3 and %d=1));

delete from tosync 
where tbname="%s" and tbid=%d and exists(select 1 from
          tosync where tbname="%s" and tbid=%d and (act=1 and %d=3 or act=3 and %d=1));
```